# Use bluetooth game controller to play/stop video in unity vr

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr, video-player

I have created a vr app in unity using google vr sdk. Currently i could click on the screen to start the video. When i use the vr headset, i need to use the bluetooth controller to play/stop the video. Can someone help me do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify how unity map your controller buttons, once you identify what button do you want to press and how unity mapped in his Input Manager (Edit->Project Settings->Input) you just need to call you function from the `Update` like this:

```c#
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1"))
    {
        playVideoFuncion();
    }
}
```

Where `playVideoFunction()` is your own fuction.
In this example I used "Fire1" but maybe in your case is different.

For example for the Xbox Controller you have this configuration explained in [Xbox 360 Controller Input on Unity](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Xbox360Controller)

If you can't find anything related on your controller you can do something like:

```c#
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Fire 1 Pressed");
    }

    if(Input.GetButtonUp("Fire2"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Fire 1 Pressed");
    }

    if(Input.GetButtonUp("0"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Button 0 pressed");
    }
    // Add more buttons and logs
}
```

There are maybe other ways to identify the input from random controllers but I don't know how. I needed the mapping for the Xbox controller and that page was useful.

Comment: "You need to identify how unity map your controller buttons"- how? i don't have much knowledge in this. so please explain. and where do i add this script?to which game object?

Comment: I expanded the answer a bit

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script and attach to the video player so that when a user clicks on the player the commands are run. I assume you already have the unity package for Google VR(GVR). Add the following sample script and modify to suit your need.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class VideoPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

private bool _isPlaying;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    _isPlaying = false
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (GvrController.ClickButtonUp && _isPlaying) {

            PlayVideo();

    }
   else if (GvrController.ClickButtonUp && !_isPlaying){

         StopVideo ();

    }


  }

public void PlayVideo{

    //Logic to Play Video
}

public void StopVideo{

    //Logic to Stop Video
}


}
```